# find the least integral value of m for [(1+i)/(1-i)]^m=1

Tags: complex-numbers

So I was doing this question and i think the answer to this question on my booklet is wrong .it says $m=4$ is the answer. I proceeded as follows:
$\left[\frac{1+i}{1-i}\right]^m=i^m$. Obviously this is true for $m=4k$. But k can also be negative right? For example $i^{-4}=1/i^{4}=1$ hence it can't be 4.

Comment: It probably means smallest natural number, because you are right, otherwise $-m$ will also work above, and if $m$ can be arbitrarily large, so $-m$ can be arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is: "find the least integral value of m for $[(1+i)/(1-i)]^m=1$".

I get the answer as $4$.

$$\bigg(\frac{1+i}{1-i} \bigg)^m=1$$
$$\bigg(\frac{(1+i)^2}{(1-i)(1+i)} \bigg)^m=1$$
$$\bigg(\frac{2i}{2} \bigg)^m=1$$
$$i^m=1$$

I guess $m > 0$ for the context here. So smallest $m$ is $4$.